# A question about the products of power set sigma algebras

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\kappa$ be the least cardinal for which the sigma algebra generated by $\{A \times B: A,B \subseteq \kappa\}$ does not contain every subset of $\kappa \times \kappa$. It is known that $\kappa$ is at least $\aleph_2$ and at most the successor of the continuum. Is it definable in terms of some standard cardinal invariant? More concretely, is it equal to the successor of the pseudo-intersection number $\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why this number cannot be $\aleph_1$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is important, but do we need to assume CH or not CH for this question?

Comment: The article "A Little Ado About Rectangles" by Aviles and Plebanek has a nice introduction to this problem.  It is available as item 50 on Aviles's site:
https://webs.um.es/avileslo/miwiki/doku.php?id=investigacion